# Moving sppkg apps from site collection to site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was tasked to move the existing apps from the parent site app catalog to the sub-site's own app catalog. i tried downloading the packages from the parent site's app catalog and uploading it to the sub site's app catalog. but when i tried adding the apps to the sub site. i got an error of "Invalid App Id:xxxxx".

How do i move the existing apps? is it possible to do what i just did?

Answer (score 0):

On SharePoint Online is App Catalog only one and default, which *"Make apps available to your organization and manage requests for apps. An app catalog is required to disable Store purchases for end users."*

Go to Central Administration of SharePoint Online > APPS section > App Catalog, here must be installed application sppkg package.

If you have enabled SiteLoading for this application, so you can install in only on any Site, [here is post about it.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection/)

There is a **Warning:** Sideloading apps is a developer/test feature **not intended for production use.**